# Windows Phone Platform and Windows Phone Applications

Tags: windows-phone, smartphone

I have a question that is bugging me and would like to have an answer.  Do all the applications available for the Windows Phone platform go through the Windows Phone store and monitored by Microsoft?  I don't possess a Windows Phone and none of my friends do, so I wanted to make sure whether all applications go through the Windows Phone store.  Thank you very much :)

Comment: Please do a cursory search next time, the answer you're looking for is: YES all applications are curated by Microsoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all applications that are available for download have to be downloaded through the Windows Phone Store.

On a sidenote, there is also the concept of dev-unlocked devices. For those, you can sideload your own applications, bypassing the store, but only limited to devices that are registered with an existing store developer account.